# Which one to use - "order" or "orders"

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following two phrases would be correct?

> with issuance of these orders, ...
>    with issuance of this order, ...

Comment: This question would be more at home on http://ell.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

How many distinct actions are being ordered?

For example, when a service member is assigned to a new duty station, he receives his 'orders.' This is a **set** of instructions, including where to be, when to be there, and various contingencies. This requires 'orders,' in plural.

If, however, one were to say 'report to the Commander immediately. That's an **order**,' the instruction is singular and thus the word 'order' describing it is also singular.

The question then is, how many specific actions are being requested? If more than one, 'orders' is appropriate. If only one, 'order' is correct.